# Buildout, Django, and Passenger

Tags: django, nginx, passenger, wsgi, buildout

I have a Django project in Buildout which I'd like to set up with my nginx server over Phusion Passenger.

The documentation for doing this doesn't seem to exist.

There seems to be a need for creating a `passenger_wsgi.py` file for setting up the WSGI environment, however I'm not sure how that will work.

Since Buildout does its own internal hacks with the Python path, how can I create and supply this file, and where in my project should I put it?

My project looks like this:

```
.
├── bin
│   ├── buildout
│   ├── django
│   ├── django.wsgi
│   ├── gunicorn
│   ├── ipython
│   ├── multiple-part-upload.py
│   ├── nosetests
│   ├── python
│   └── test
├── conf
│   ├── deploy
│   ├── shared
│   └── vagrant
├── src
│   ├── myproject
│   └── myproject.egg-info
├── bootstrap.py
├── bower.json
├── buildout.cfg
├── README.mkd
├── setup.py
└── Vagrantfile
```

Where should I put `passenger_wsgi.py` so that a) Passenger will find it and b) my Buildout eggs will be included in the path?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Buildout, but the point of passenger_wsgi.py is to provide a WSGI entry point that Phusion Passenger can use. How do you start gunicorn in this project? That may give some hints on how to construct passenger_wsgi.py.

Comment: It looks like I need to develop a Buildout recipe to generate the `passenger_wsgi.py` file with the correct sandboxed Buildout paths.